# $3 \times 3$ matrix with determinant a large power of $2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, elementary-number-theory, determinant

Here's a little curiosity I found.  The following $3 \times 3$ matrix has entries that are distinct primes $< 100$ and its determinant is $2^{19}$.
$$ \pmatrix{71 & 31 & 97\cr 61 & 67 & 23\cr 7 & 83 & 73}$$
Does anyone know of another such matrix whose determinant is nonzero and divisible by a larger power of $2$?  If not, what is the least $p$ such that there is a $3 \times 3$ matrix with entries distinct primes $\le p$ and determinant nonzero and divisible by a larger power of $2$?  What if we drop the requirement of the entries being primes (and allow distinct positive integers $\le p$)?

Comment: With little effort I found this $2\times2$ example:  $\begin{vmatrix}3&13\\5&43\end{vmatrix}=2^6$

Comment: You can do better than that: try for $2^{12}$ in a $2 \times 2$.

Comment: You mean like $\begin{vmatrix}71&3\\31&59\end{vmatrix}$?

Comment: $a_{11}=61,a_{12}=5,a_{21}=47,a_{22}=71$.

Comment: or $\begin{vmatrix}71&89\\17&79\end{vmatrix}$?

Comment: Any $3\times 3$ matrix with distinct prime entries $<100$ will have determinant strictly less than $2^{22}$ (via Hadamard and AM-GM)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To get determinant $2^{20}$, we require to include **one** additional prime number: $101$, and one of such examples will be:
$$ \det \pmatrix{101 & 17 & 67 \cr 61 & 97 & 3\cr 7 & 83 & 89} = 2^{20}.$$

**(updated)**

Here is list of examples of matrices with distinct prime entries with determinants of the form $2^d$ (note that I'm not sure that those $p_{max}$ are absolutely correct: some of them probably could be improved a bit):
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
d & p_{max}& matrix & det \\
\hline
20 & 101 & \pmatrix{101 & 79 & 2 \cr 13 & 83 & 89 \cr 71 & 17 & 97} & 2^{20} \\
\hline
21 & 127 & \pmatrix{127 & 107 & 19 \cr 3 & 109 & 103 \cr 89 & 5 & 101} & 2^{21}\\
\hline
22 & 151 & \pmatrix{151 & 139 & 13 \cr 3 & 127 & 137 \cr 103 & 19 & 149} & 2^{22}\\
\hline
23 & 181 & \pmatrix{181 & 167 & 3 \cr 11 & 157 & 179 \cr 163 & 13 & 151} & 2^{23}\\
\hline
24 & 229 & \pmatrix{229 & 193 & 13 \cr 7 & 191 & 227 \cr 181 & 3 & 223} & 2^{24}\\
\hline
25 & 277 & \pmatrix{277 & 241 & 3 \cr 7 & 269 & 271 \cr 257 & 29 & 263} & 2^{25} \\
\hline
26 & 349 & \pmatrix{349 & 317 & 3 \cr 5 & 337 & 331 \cr 313 & 13 & 311} & 2^{26} \\
\hline
27 & \underline{431} & \pmatrix{431 & 389 & 3 \cr 7 & 409 & 419 \cr 397 & 17 & 421} & 2^{27} \\
\hline
28 & 557 & \pmatrix{557 & 463 & 3 \cr 5 & 541 & 499 \cr 509 & 17 & 523} & 2^{28} \\
\hline
29 & 677 & \pmatrix{677 & 673 & 5 \cr 43 & 659 & 647 \cr 661 & 37 & 641} & 2^{29} \\
\hline
30 & 853 & \pmatrix{853 & 811 & 79 \cr 3 & 839 & 829 \cr 809 & 5 & 823} & 2^{30} \\
\hline
31 & 1063 & \pmatrix{1063 & 1051 & 3 \cr 13 & 1039 & 971 \cr 1049 & 43 & 1031} & 2^{31} \\
\hline
32 & 1321 & \pmatrix{1321 & 1289 & 17 \cr 31 & 1319 & 1279 \cr 1301 & 11 & 1291} & 2^{32} \\
\hline
\cdots \\
\end{array}

---

If drop the requirement of the entries being primes, and consider matrices with distinct entries (less than $100$), then there are examples with $2^{20}$:
$$ \det \pmatrix{99 & 81 & 10\cr 5 & 96 & 86\cr 87 & 26 & 82} = 2^{20},$$
$$ \det \pmatrix{96 & 94 & 6\cr 35 & 86 & 85\cr 91 & 8 & 87} = 2^{20};$$

---

odd (but not all prime) entries:
$$ \det \pmatrix{99 & 95 & 5\cr 23 & 93 & 89\cr 85 & 31 & 91} = 2^{20}.$$

---

It looks like the largest possible determinant of a matrix with distinct positive entries less than $100$ is $1742902\approx 2^{20.733}$ (or close to this number):
$$
\det\pmatrix{99 & 3 & 95\cr 94 & 98 & 1\cr 2 & 96 & 97} = 1742902,
$$
so there is no hope to find any $3\times 3$ such matrix with determinant $2^{21}$.

Comment: How did you find these examples?

Comment: @lhf: simply computer search among random $3\times 3$ matrices with restrictions for their entries.

Comment: @Oleg567: Have you shown that $2^{20}$ is impossible with primes less than $100$?  I note that there are $3\times 3$ matrices of distinct primes all under $100$ with determinant greater than $2^{20}$.  For example, $ \det \pmatrix{97 & 73 & 3 \cr 7 & 89 & 71\cr 79 & 2 & 83} = 1048758 = 2^{20}+182.$

Comment: @paw88789: actually my calculations show that the closest to $2^{20}$ value for the discussed set is 
$$\det\pmatrix{97 & 71 & 33\cr 5 & 89 & 83\cr 73 & 2 & 79} = 1048588=2^{20} + 12.$$
I get this value many times, and no one closer.

The maximal value for determinant on $3\times 3$ matrices with distinct prime numbers $<100$ is (I believe)
$$\det\pmatrix{97 & 5 & 73\cr 71 & 89 & 2\cr 3 & 79 & 83} =1061744 \approx 2^{20.018},$$
which can "say" that the values of required determinants aren't too dense around  $2^{20}$.

Comment: @paw88789: sorry, typo... there should be $$ \det \pmatrix{97 & 71 & \color{red}{3} \cr 5 & 89 & 83\cr 73 & 2 & 79} = 1048588 \approx 2^{20}+12 $$ in previous comment.

Comment: @lhf: to find examples of $2^{20}, \ldots, 2^{30}, \ldots$, I considered candidates of the form $$ \det \pmatrix{L & L & s \cr s & L & L\cr L & s & L} ,$$ where $L -$ pretty large numbers, $s -$ pretty small ones.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that we can infer the least prime p such that determinant is $2^n$ by using the relation determinant <$2p^3.$
The least prime will satisfy the inequality $2^n<2p^3<2^{(n+1)}.$

```
        expected range   actual prime  
2^20:    80-101            101
2^21:    101-128           127
2^22:    128-161           157
2^30:    812-1024          853
2^31:    1024-1290          ?
```

$$\pmatrix{a & b & c\cr d & e & f\cr g & h & i}$$

Above determinant is given below.

$$a(ei - fh) - b(di - fg) + c(dh - eg)$$

Let's assume $3 \times 3$ matrix with entries are distinct positive integer $<100.$
Maximum value of determinant $2 \times 2$ matrix<$99^2<2.4\times2^{12}.$
$3 \times 3$ matrix has the following properties.
If $(ei - fh)$ and $(dh - eg)$ are positive, $(di - fg)$ will always be positive.  I checked that by brute force.
Hence  we get

\begin{align}
a(ei - fh) - b(di - fg) + c(dh - eg)&<(a+c)\times 2.4\times2^{12}\\
&<200\times2.4\times2^{12}\\
&<2^{21}\\
\end{align}

Hence maximum $2^n$ of determinant $3 \times 3$ matrix=$2^{20}.$

Result of brute force search.
$3 \times 3$ matrix with entries are distinct primes $<100.$

Case: Not all entries are prime.
Determinant is $2^{20}$.

$$\pmatrix{71 & 3 & 89\cr 83 & 79 & 13\cr 11 & 97 & 93}$$
$$\pmatrix{73 & 5 & 83\cr 89 & 79 & 11\cr 7 & 91 & 93}$$
$$\pmatrix{83 & 13 & 79\cr 89 & 71 & 5\cr 3 & 93 & 95}$$

Case: All entries are prime.

It seems that there is no solution for determinant is $2^n$ with $n>19.$
There are many matrices with determinant is $2^{19}.$
For example,
$$\pmatrix{3 & 5 & 79\cr 83 & 13 & 23\cr 29 & 89 & 71}$$
$$\pmatrix{3 & 11 & 79\cr 83 & 7 & 59\cr 39 & 89 & 53}$$
$$\pmatrix{39 & 3 & 59\cr 89 & 61 & 5\cr 7 & 79 & 71}$$

Comment: Well yes, but I did mention "primes $< 100$".

Comment: I didn't notice it.